# What gets executed when you don't specify the extention on the command line?

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, bash

I installed [uglifyjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglify-js) node package.  It got installed into the `C:\Users\sam\AppData\Roaming\npm` folder which happens to be in the PATH, so that I could execute it from anywhere.

To understand what gets executed, I ran the `where uglifyjs` command and got the following:

```
C:\Users\sam\AppData\Roaming\npm\uglifyjs
C:\Users\sam\AppData\Roaming\npm\uglifyjs.cmd
```

And sure enough there are 2 files.  The `.cmd` is a batch file and the one without the extension is a bash script.

When I run `uglifyjs` from the command line, what gets executed?

Comment: Only the CMD one. Where finds any file not executables only. What executables extensions CMD searches is in `%PathExt%`.

Comment: @Mark To clarify, are you saying that the `where` command returns all the matches from `%PATH%` directories regardless of whether they are executable or not?

Comment: @Mark Follow up question.  If there are 5 copies of `uglifyjs.cmd` in various `%PATH%` directories, will the 1st one returned by the `where` command be the one that Windows executes?

Comment: Yes. Type `where /?`.  _The search is also done by appending the
 extensions of the PATHEXT variable to the pattern._

Comment: Where returns anything matching the pattern you gave and known executables extensions appended to your pattern. You pattern was a file without an extension.

Comment: @Mark That makes sense.  I am trying to find out which of the 5 uglifyjs.cmd files Windows will execute when I type in `uglifyjs` at the command line.  Is the `where` command the right way to find out?  Meaning can I rely on the order of items returned from this command?

Comment: Yes you can. The order of execution for CMD is current directory then the path, same as `where` without switches.